# Service worker is sending old messages to subscribers

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker, web-push

I'm trying to send web push notification and everything working great. But now I'm facing a problem. I don't know why but service-worker is sending old messages to everyone.

**service-worker.js**

```
const applicationServerPublicKey = 'BFcmZ847NIPORvhzARrLcIFfShkxnHGsiKSlYvUe0WaPNHFHGH3FXRWwunSHjktJgcunbtteTu_xmDw6iugygic';

/* eslint-enable max-len */

function urlB64ToUint8Array(base64String) {
  const padding = '='.repeat((4 - base64String.length % 4) % 4);
  const base64 = (base64String + padding)
    .replace(/\-/g, '+')
    .replace(/_/g, '/');

  const rawData = window.atob(base64);
  const outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length);

  for (let i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) {
    outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return outputArray;
}

self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
    self.skipWaiting();

  console.log('[Service Worker] Push Received.');
  console.log(`[Service Worker] Push had this data: "${event.data.text()}"`);

  const title = 'Example Website';
  const options = {
    body: 'Content',
    icon: 'http://www.example.com/icon.jpg',
    "image": "http://www.example.com/img.jpg",
    };

  event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  console.log('[Service Worker] Notification click Received.');

  event.notification.close();

  event.waitUntil(
    clients.openWindow('http://www.example.com')
  );
});

self.addEventListener('pushsubscriptionchange', function(event) {
  console.log('[Service Worker]: \'pushsubscriptionchange\' event fired.');
  const applicationServerKey = urlB64ToUint8Array(applicationServerPublicKey);
  event.waitUntil(
    self.registration.pushManager.subscribe({
      userVisibleOnly: true,
      applicationServerKey: applicationServerKey
    })
    .then(function(newSubscription) {
      // TODO: Send to application server
      console.log('[Service Worker] New subscription: ', newSubscription);
    })
  );
});
```

I think browser caching this static JS file. I'm not sure yet. But I am not able send new message to subscribers. Please help me with it.

Please help me with it.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to update a service worker at the moment.

I've wrote many articles about updating a service worker on the Pushpad blog:

- [Update the service worker and the scripts imported with importScripts](http://blog.pushpad.xyz/2017/05/update-the-service-worker-and-the-scripts-imported-with-importscripts/)
- For dependencies: [Service worker: importScripts never updates scripts](http://blog.pushpad.xyz/2016/07/service-worker-importscripts-never-updates-scripts/)
- For debugging: [Inspect service workers with Chrome](http://blog.pushpad.xyz/2017/05/inspect-service-workers-with-chrome/)

Basically you need to:

> 1. Visit a page of the website (that activates the service worker or calls serviceWorker.register) – sometimes you also need to refresh that page
> 2. Now the new service worker is installed, but it can’t be activated until you terminate the previous service worker: close and reopen the browser

Answer (score 0):

You have three mechanisms to update a serviceworker:

- Update the serviceworker script; even a comment will do it, and visit a page controlled by the service worker. This update will trigger a download in the background of the serviceworker file, and if there is any difference you will enter the update life cycle for the serviceworker: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/service-workers#update-a-service-worker
- Another option is to unregister and re-register the serviceworker.
- Last option is to call the `.update()` method, but unfortunately as per today is just implemented in Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/update

Comment: `service-worker.js` is updating on my computer, but not on other computers. My subscribers are getting old messages ( Push Notification ). 

Is there any other way to send multiple data (e.g. title, link, image url, etc.) to `service-worker.js` so it can send notification?

Comment: The payload that you send via the push message, it's completely up to you. In theory, you can send all those fields; your serviceworker needs to know they exist and show the notification accordingly.